# Magento: Product ID by SKU (JavaScript / Client Side)

Tags: javascript, php, magento, request, product

Is there a way to somehow request the product ID with the SKU as a client without access to the server?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: would possible through soap api but it still requires authentication. Define what you mean by "a client without access to the server"

Comment: basically i want to get the product id of a product on the adidas website (which is based on magento where i live)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your answer i assume you want to scrap magento product id from a 3rd party store.

The most solid way to do this, is to read it from hidden field in addtocart form.

Comment: Thanks, already figured out this possible solution. However, I wondered if there was another one, in case the product page is not online or accessible yet.

Comment: i strongly doubt this is possible

Comment: Thanks for the answer